# Searching users on LinkedIn using Python-LinkedIn

Tags: python, api, linkedin-api

I am new to python programming. I am trying to access LinkedIn data using pyhton.
I have performed all the steps mentioned at https://ozgur.github.io/python-linkedin/

When I run the code to get profile, i get the desired result but if I try to code anything else (like search_profile() or get_group(41001)) I get the following error
**LinkedInError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url:**

The code that have written is below:

```
API_KEY = "xyz"
API_SECRET = "abc"
RETURN_URL = "http://localhost:8080/testPrj/auth/linkedin"
Access_Token = "abcdef"

application = linkedin.LinkedInApplication(token=Access_Token)
application.get_profile()  # No Error
application.get_group(41001) # Error
application.search_profile(selectors=[{'people':['first_name','last_name']}]) # Error
```

Can someone help me to understand what is this issue and how to solve it ?

Thanks !!!

Comment: Are you sure you are giving `application = linkedin.LinkedInApplication(token=Access_Token)` the right input? The [docs](https://ozgur.github.io/python-linkedin/) have it like this: `authentication = linkedin.LinkedInAuthentication(API_KEY, API_SECRET, RETURN_URL, linkedin.PERMISSIONS.enums.values())`, then: `application = linkedin.LinkedInApplication(authentication)` --> i.e. more needed than just the token.

Comment: The code        authentication = linkedin.LinkedInAuthentication(API_KEY, API_SECRET, RETURN_URL, linkedin.PERMISSIONS.enums.values()) is use to get the authorization code which is then used to get the access token. We use this token to access the linkedin data.  Hence I am using    application.get_profile()